# Laravel 5.8 email verify with multiple guards

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8, laravel-6

I am trying to add verify email function in Laravel 5.8 i have 2 custom guards and need email verification for both guards. I am successfully verifying it for first guard but for 2nd guard verify email is not working.

Here is my verification controller.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:guard1');
    $this->middleware('signed')->only('verify');
    $this->middleware('throttle:6,1')->only('verify', 'resend');
}
```

If i add another line of `$this->middleware('auth:guard2');` in construct function both of my verifications are not working.  can anyone help me here how to send verification email for multiple guards and verify their emails?

Thanks!